# How do I merge two procedures into one?

Tags: eclipse, stored-procedures, merge, sql-scripts, hana-sql-script

I am trying to merge two procedures into one. Is there any way?

I am using SQL script for this. I am using eclipse for this procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there is no such feature in Eclipse (HANA Studio). The easiest way to do it yourself, would be to copy the body of the called (including BEGIN and END so you don't get problems with variable scope if variable names are used in both procedures, but should be destinct) and add declarations for the procedure parameters if they have different names than the variables you bind them to.

Note that SQLScript Optimizer will inline your procedures if possible, so for performance reason normally there should be no need to embed one procedure into another.